# maven install in eclipse jre error :

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

When I run maven install from eclipse, I get the below error. 
I have JRE6 in my installed JRE's in

Window - preferences - Java - Installed JREs

```
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) 
.....
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
  C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\..\lib\tools.jar
Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
In most cases you can change the location of your Java
installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
```

I have set the JAVA_HOME correctly in environment variables - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45 , and can see the same when I execute java -version from command prompt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says , it is unable to locate Javac compiler.
JRE doesn't have the compiler. You need JDK.

In Window - preferences - Java - Installed JREs, Add your JDK/jre..

say C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre

Comment: This works. My error log also said 'In most cases you can change the location of your Java installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable'. I already set it, still the error came. So I think I should have set that up in eclipse settings too!